# RL Invertible Value Function approach - why it prevents rewards from exploding?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Authors of ["Recurrent Experience Replay in Destributed RL", page 3](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1lyTjAqYX), use the function $h$ to prevent rewards from exploding:

$$h(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x)(\sqrt{|x|+1} -1) + \epsilon x$$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small number, for example $0.0001$ and $x$ is the score (aka reward). h re-scales the rewards the network receives.

This is different to a more common "reward-clipping" technique.

[image]

---

**Question 1 (most important):**

The Q-vaue formula looks like this:

$$y = h \bigg( nstepReward + \gamma^n \cdot h^{-1}(Q(s_{t+n}, a^*)) \bigg)$$

Why do authors pass the Q-scores through the inverse (exponential) function and then through the squashing function $h$? The effect of this is that Q-target-scores remain unchanged, because composition of a function and its inverse is identity. So to me, the $Q$ is still a big source of threat of "exploding rewards", because it's left untouched. Why do we keep it untouched?

It looks like the whole formula merely squashes $nStepReward$, but why not just squash everything, including Q to prevent exploding rewards? In other words, why not to have:

$$y = h \bigg( nstepReward + \gamma^n Q(s_{t+n}, a^*) \bigg)$$

---

**Question 2:**

Why to use $\epsilon x$ in the formula for $h$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from one of the authors:

> A bit more intuitively, think of the neural network being asked to
>   produce a scaled variant of the q-function, namely $P(s,a) = h(Q(s,a))$ 
>   The Bellman equation reads:
>
> $$Q(s,a) = R + \gamma * Q(s', a')$$
>
> and by applying function $h$ to both sides you get, equivalently,
>
> $$P(s,a) = h(Q(s,a)) $$
>   $$= h ( R + \gamma * Q(s', a') ) $$
>   $$= h ( R + \gamma * h^{-1}( P (s', a') ) )$$
>
> So hopefully this makes it clear that the target for the network's
>   output at (s,a) should be $$h ( R + \gamma * h^{-1} ( P (s', a') ) )$$  where
>   $P (s', a')$ is the same network's output at the next state.

---

From my original post: *"these Q is a still big source of "exploding rewards" threat ... these destination Q are free to grow as large as they wish."*
With the author's help I realised that they are actually not "entirely free to grow" in the way I though originally:

We should not forget that these "destination scores" were downscaled themselves - as the yellow-quote formula tells, they will be  $h(P(s',a'))$ themselves.

So we need to "unpack" them before we can add the currently observed reward.  **Thus, we won't have exploding rewards in the long run, and we also don't have 
to truncate any reward-ratios by using the old-school reward clipping**  ...That's a very clever way to do it! :)

The yellow-quote formula tells us to:

1. quickly restore (un-shrink) the downscaled destination $h(P)$,
2. apply discount and reward,
3. then downscale it back.  It now can be the "downscaled destination", for any states earlier in time.  Stepping back in time, we begin from 1) and process earlier state in the same fashion.

The goal is to make the network learn to predict these "downscaled destinations", and it's a lot nicer - because these destination scores are smaller due to being downscaled. 
There will be no huge gradient entering the network, since the differences are a lot smaller.

---

**P.S.**

Don't forget that $h^{-1}$ is NOT $\frac{1}{h}$

Instead, google for what an inverse function is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your first question can be answered by considering when you do not step forward and $n = 0$. So what happend in your case? $y = h(Q(S_t, a^*))$. However, $y= Q(S_t, a^*)$ could be more reasonable. Hence, we need that $h^{-1}$ to have a more explainable reward in the edge case.

One answer to the second question could back to the differentiation of the $h$ function. If the $\epsilon x$ is removed, the $\frac{dh(x)}{dx}$ goes to zero when $x$ grows. But, by the presence of $\epsilon$, we will have $\frac{dh(x)}{dx} \to \epsilon$ for big enough values of $x$. Hence, the reward function will not cap for the big values of $x$ and grows increasingly.

Comment: Thank you @OmG. It's strange to me, because I though we don't need to back-propagate through $h$ or $h^{-1}$.  If I remember correctly, our backpropagation will start with initial values of $Q_{observed} - Q_{predicted}$.  Or in the case of this formula we will have $y - Q_{predicted}$. We can then pass this value through a single neuron representing the action (all sibling neurons receive a zero), and keep computing the gradient while it keeps flowing down through the activation functions of the network layers, and through its matrices.